# Bash Find with ignore

Tags: bash, find

I need to find files and ignore files like "^02" (it is regex). If "^02" is directory, then I need to ignore every files, which are inside directory. I don't know how to do it. I tried to use something like.

```
find . -type f -not -regex "^9" -o -prune
```

But it doesn't works.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the regex doesn't use `^` and `$` as it always has to match the whole string. Moreover, the path starts with `./` if the first argument to `find` is `.`, so you need to include it, too.

```
find -type f -not -regex '\./02.*'
```

If you want to exclude even subdirectories, use `.*/02.*` for the regex.

If you want to only exclude the directories matching the pattern, but you want to keep the files, you need to use `prune` only for directories matching the regex, and `-false` to remove the directories from the list:

```
find . -type d -regex '\./02.*' -prune -false -or -type f
```

Also, you can use patterns instead of regexes for simple cases. That way, you can use `-name` to include subdirectories:

```
find . -name '02*' -prune -false -or -type f
```